# Can I update the scaling config on App Engine Flexible without a full redeploy?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I'm just getting started with App Engine Flexible and it seems like the only way to update any configuration, including `automatic_scaling` or `manual_scaling` settings is to update `app.yaml`, then do a redeployment via `gcloud app deploy`. Let's say I have a relatively conservative configuration to ensure that costs don't get out of hand, but suddenly get 100x traffic and need to change the configuration to allow more aggressive scaling. The problem is, a full deploy takes about 10 minutes.

Is there any way to change scaling settings in a faster way, without a full redeployment (using the same existing app code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that would be possible using the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/) sending a Patch REST request to [apps.services.versions.patch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch)
Depending on your [use case](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/apis) you can either use REST, RPC, or even the Client Library itself to do so.

Comment: Is this currently not integrated with the gcloud CLI tool at all?

Comment: Additionally, if you are expecting to suddenly get 100x traffic, I would suggest you to go with App Engine Standard which is more suited for rapid scaling. You can check [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments) the differences between both environments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Python snippet like this, that uses the App Engine Admin API as in the other answer:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
import os

service = discovery.build('appengine', 'v1')
projectId = os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
serviceId = 'default'
versionsId='20190130t220207'

body = {
  "automaticScaling": {
    "minTotalInstances": 3
  },
  "env": "flex"
}

minInstancesRequest = service.apps().services().versions().patch(appsId=projectId, servicesId=serviceId, versionsId=versionsId, body=body, updateMask='automaticScaling.minTotalInstances')
minInstancesRequest.execute()
```